# Hidden limitation of Assumptions (Is $x^2 < 0$ contradictory)?

Tags: assumptions

Is there a limitation of `Assuming` that I am not aware of?  I would like to assume that the square of a number is negative:

```
Assuming[x^2 < 0, Simplify[Sqrt[x^2]]]
```

[image]

> `x`

Why is `$Assumptions` generating a message that `x^2 < 0` is a contradictory assumption?

Comment: A more minimal example is `$Assumptions = x^2 < 0`

Comment: Compare with `Reduce[x^2 < 0, x]` --> `False` and the statement in the documentation that "Reduce assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically in inequalities are real, while all other quantities are complex." The assumption can be overridden. `Reduce[x^2 < 0, x, Complexes]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) documentation states that

> Quantities that appear algebraically in inequalities are always assumed to be real.

Thus in `x^2 < 0` the variable `x` is assumed to be real. That is why the assumption is contradictory.

A shorter example is

```
$Assumptions = x^2 < 0

During evaluation of $Assumptions::cas: Warning: contradictory assumption(s) x^2<0 encountered.

(* x^2 < 0 *)
```

---

Other functions, such as [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html), also make similar automatic assumptions. This is also documented for `Reduce`.

```
Reduce[x^2 < 0, x]
(* False *)
```

However, with `Reduce`, it is possible to override this automatic assumption.

```
Reduce[x^2 < 0, x, Complexes]
(* Re[x] == 0 && (Im[x] < 0 || Im[x] > 0) *)
```

I do not know if this is possible with `Assumptions`.

Comment: Couldn't you use the output of your last `Reduce` for `$Assumptions`?  Or one could use `x^2 \[Element] Reals && Re[x^2] < 0` (the `Re` seems to keep `$Assumptions` from complaining).

Comment: @MichaelE2 It sounds like a good idea. It's just that `Sqrt[x^2]` can't be simplified to `x`  correctly with these assumptions, e.g. `(-I)^2 == I^2 == -1`.

Comment: If you add the assumption `Im[x] > 0` (resp. `Im[x] < 0`), then `Simplify` will return `x` (resp. `-x`).  It's not clear to me that getting `x` is the desired outcome, though.